# About Jean-Yves Girard

Tags: logic, soft-question, linear-logic

I am student and I'm studying linear logic. I saw a quote in a book:

"I'm not a linear logician" - Jean-Yves Girard. Tokyo, April 1996.

I searched on Google but I did not find the context of why he said it. What he meant by that phrase?

Comment: This is off-topic. You should probably just email him and ask.

Comment: @rschwieb: What if the question were about a person no longer living, would you give the same advice? For me, the question is very much on-topic: clear, succint, provides context, and the OP hopes for a precise answer, not for a vague discussion; what more could I ask for? The fact that it is partly biographical doesn't make it off-topic: it asks about a (famous) logician, not about Michael Jackson, and the question doesn't concern his life, but the way he sees his relationship with linear logic (his creation).

Comment: This is just a guess, but the date and location seem to tie it to a specific conference.  See https://keio.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/preface-volume-3-issue-1 -- it's possible the quote is in one of the papers there.

Comment: This question is not off-topic and should not be closed. Well done to Laura for contacting Girard and reporting the answer here: Girard's answer should be preserved here for posterity as a classic of its kind. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 22):

As suggested by @rschwieb, I sent an email to Girard. Here is his answer:

> Hi,
>
> The general idea is that logic should not have an adjective: look
>   at modal, non-monotonic, paraconsistent logics in which the 
>   adjective is a sort of negation, like in « military justice ».
>
> Linear logic is just a way to do plain logic, i.e. to study pure reasoning.
>   My position was that linearity is a question of fine structure: even if you
>   are concerned with intuitionism, the use of linearimplication can be very 
>   helpful.
>
> More recently I discovered that predicate calculus is based on a mistake,
>   namely the idea of « a property of individuals » P(t): we cannot speak of
>   « blue » but only say « the sky is blue ». This realistic contraption makes
>   equality a nonsense. It is indeed possible to expel the « individuals » and
>   replace them, when needed, with linear propositions T, U, V, in which case
>   equality becomes linear equivalence. For this we absolutely need linearity
>   since we can prove (classically or intuitionistically) that there are no
>   more than two « individuals ».
>
> To sum up, I am not a linear logician because the natural treatment of logic
>   compels us into using linearity, this independently of any commitment.
>
> Best regards,
>
> J-YG

Answer (score 5):

To put this in context, one of Girard's several claims to fame is being the inventor of *linear logic*, a specialized kind of logic with applications in theoretical computer science and several other places.

If he denies being a "linear logician", it could either be understood as a way to distance himself from that particular system (it's old hat to him, he has long since moved on), or as a way to stress that linear logic is not all he does, or even as a way to say that there's no such thing as a "linear logician" at all (i.e. that linear logic is not a philosophical position one can take instead of ordinary logic, but merely an interesting game one can choose to play when it makes sense).

Or perhaps he meant something completely different. He is often not an easy person to understand and seems to have a fondness for provocative phrasings that the listener is left to make sense of for himself. I once had the experience of sitting through a series of several very animated lectures by him at a summer school, and only getting the faintest idea what he was doing, or what he was trying to achieve. Later on, I followed some other lectures by one of his colleagues who tried to explain his work more accessibly, but who admitted up front that he was not entirely sure he understood it correctly ...

Since the quote is attributed to a particular *time and place* (apparently a meeting/workshop about linear logic specifically), it looks likely to me that it must have been an off-the-cuff spoken remark by Girard during the meeting, perhaps seizing the opportunity to crack a joke at the expense of someone saying, for example, "we're all linear logicians here". If something like that is the case, looking for a deeper meaning in the statement is almost certainly futile.

Unless the book where you found the quote uses it to illustrate an explicit point, I would guess it's just there because the author found it funny.

Comment: I've actually seen it written at, at least, two different places in his own articles or reviews (modulo memory problems). What I've understood from this is that he instantly recognized that linear logic, which was originally "invented" to make sense of quantum mechanics, failed to answer its original motives. So I guess to him, its a way to say "I'm still looking for a good framework to explain QM, and linear logic isn't one so I'm not a linear logician".